# Rails 3.1 Sqlite3 Error On Push To Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails 3.1 app that i am trying to push to Heroku. It keeps failing when i push it.

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Thanks!
       /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
```

I changed my gem file to have the following lines:

```
gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]
gem 'pg', :group => [:production]
```

Even after running bundle install etc i am getting the error. I even ran some tests without sqlite3 in my gem file and it still tries to install it on Heroku. Any suggestions?

Comment: just checking that you have commited your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and then pushed them to heroku? Also, which stack are you using on heroku?

Comment: Yes i have committed everything and pushed it all to heroku, or tried rather. I am trying to use Cedar since that is what you need to use for Rails 3.1

Comment: that's only true if you want to use the asset pipeline, Rails 3.1 will run on the other stacks.

Answer (score 2):

Lol it turns out i was working on one branch and was pushing my master. Once i merged them and pushed the correct branch everything worked great.

Comment: [This guy had the same problem as you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8007353/456814).

Answer (score 1):

The Cedar stack doesn't yet support `bundle without` according to the docs, http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler so it will still attempt to install it on deployment.

To be honest, you'd be much better using postgres locally if that is what you're deploying too.

Comment: Is there a way to switch it over now that i've been using sqlite3?

Comment: sure, if you use heroku db:push locally it will push your SQLlite DB into postgres (if you want your local data at Heroku). Reconfigure your development database (config/database.yml) to be postgres and then do a heroku db:pull to pull it back from Heroku.

Comment: Well i would do that if i could actually get it on Heroku to begin with.

Comment: a solution would be remove the reference to sqllite - deploy to heroku so it's actully working on pg. Then readd sqlite locally and do the heroku db:push