# Heroku does not accept push even though I have sqlite in development block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler

I have the following lines in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end        

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I also ran `bundle install` to have my `Gemfile.lock` updated.

When I push to heroku I still get the following error:

```
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you bundle + commit  before pushing?

Comment: Yes. I did checkin both the Gemfile and the Gemfile.lock

Comment: Voting to close as "no longer reproducible" because the problem was simply that the original poster [pushed the wrong branch to Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8007353/456814).

Comment: Close vote retracted, because apparently [sometimes people forget to push the right branch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7879067/456814). Should just close as a duplicate of that, but I've already used up my close vote `:P`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hoppla. I made quite a silly mistake here. I was currently working on a branch but I pushed the master branch to Herokum, like I was used to.

So `git push heroku master` did push an old version of the branch, which did of course not contain my changes to the Gemfile.

Comment: This helped me realize that after I made a change to the Gemfile in my app. I forgot to push the changes to github first then push them up to heroku master. Once I did that the project was pushed to heroku, and everything worked.

Answer (score 9):

I had `sqlite3` in development block, but I had recently installed [`mailcatcher`](http://mailcatcher.me/), a useful gem to catch sent emails and display them to you in your browser.

`mailcatcher` has `sqlite3` as a dependency. Moving it back where it belongs fixed the problem:

```
group :development, :test  do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'mailcatcher'
end
```

If you have this error but are sure you do not include `sqlite3` outside of the development mode, look for other gem requiring it.

Comment: Helped a lot thanks, I forgot I had recently installed mailcatcher. I had include `gem 'thin'` in all environments too.