# Heroku push fails because of SQLite, yet I thought I removed it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I changed 'sqlite3' in my Gemfile to 'pg' and also changed the code in database.yml so that it is now

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

yet in my console, when I run `git push heroku master`, I get

```
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I made sure that my Gemfile didn't have anything except the rails defaults.

Here is the contents of the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# gem 'doorkeeper'
# gem 'passenger'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: did you bundle after removing sqlite from your Gemfile?

Comment: there should be problem with Gemfile.lock, check `Gemfile.lock` for `sqlite`, and if you find it then run `bundle install` and commit `Gemfile.lock` it should get deployed on heroku.

Comment: Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007297/heroku-does-not-accept-push-even-though-i-have-sqlite-in-development-block

I was pushing the wrong branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think RKP is correct - you've probably got `sqlite3` in your `GemFile.lock` still

I'd get rid of it like this:

```
#dev environment
bundle install

git add .
git commit -a -m "SQLite3"
git push heroku master
```